How can I manage to detect multipath devices before assembling md RAID in Debian boot?
I have the following situation:
I am using 12 SAS disks, with redundant controllers, in a md-RAID6 in Debian.
Usually multipathd handles the multipathing, resulting in a device-mapper configuration where, for example /dev/sda and /dev/sdb are the paths for /dev/dm-0 alias /dev/mapper/mpatha
My /dev/md0 is then assembled out of dm-[0..11].
However when rebooting mdadm handles the array far before device-mapper resulting in my array being build out of single-path /dev/sd* instead of the mapped devices (which can't be created if the block devices are busy due to mdadm already having opened them).
E.g. I get the following logs in dmesg
[    9.052828] device-mapper: table: 254:3: multipath: error getting device (-EBUSY)
[    9.052939] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table

My understanding is, that this is all handled by udev inside the initramfs. However I currently lack the understanding to change the behaviour so that the multipaths would be handled before mdadm. Can anyone provide any advice on how to achieve this?
For better understanding here is another overview over my configuration:
root@xyz# multipath -l
[...]
mpathb (35000c500a77207af) dm-11 SEAGATE,STMFSND2CLAR4000
size=3.6T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='service-time 0' prio=0 status=active
  |- 1:0:22:0 sdw  65:96 active undef running
  `- 1:0:37:0 sdaj 66:48 active undef running
[...]

root@xyz# dmsetup status
mpathb: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:96 A 0 0 1 66:48 A 0 0 1
mpathc: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:0 A 0 0 1 65:208 A 0 0 1
mpathd: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:48 A 0 0 1 66:0 A 0 0 1
mpathe: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:64 A 0 0 1 66:16 A 0 0 1
mpathf: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:80 A 0 0 1 66:32 A 0 0 1
mpathg: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 8:240 A 0 0 1 65:192 A 0 0 1
mpathh: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:32 A 0 0 1 65:240 A 0 0 1
mpathi: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:112 A 0 0 1 66:64 A 0 0 1
mpathj: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 8:208 A 0 0 1 65:160 A 0 0 1
mpathk: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 8:224 A 0 0 1 65:176 A 0 0 1
mpathl: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:16 A 0 0 1 65:224 A 0 0 1
mpathm: 0 7814037168 multipath 2 0 0 0 1 1 A 0 2 2 65:128 A 0 0 1 66:80 A 0 0 1

root@xyz# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
md0 : active raid6 dm-11[0] dm-10[4] dm-9[3] dm-8[2] dm-7[6] dm-6[10] dm-5[1] dm-4[5] dm-3[11] dm-2[7] dm-1[9] dm-0[8]
      39068861440 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [12/12] [UUUUUUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

Thanks in advance!
